What does the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cget_managed_ptr'" mean?
I'm trying to train a model with very standard HF code I've used before:
import os
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
from datasets import load_dataset
import torch
from pathlib import Path
import glob

def preprocess_function_proofnet_simple(examples: dict[str, list], tokenizer, max_length: int = 1024) -> dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
    """
    Preprocess the input data for the proofnet dataset.

    Args:
    examples: The examples to preprocess.
    tokenizer: The tokenizer for encoding the texts.

    Returns:
    The processed model inputs.
    """
    inputs = [f"{examples['nl_statement'][i]}{tokenizer.eos_token}{examples['formal_statement'][i]}" for i in range(len(examples['nl_statement']))]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, max_length=max_length, padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    labels = model_inputs.input_ids.clone()
    labels[labels == tokenizer.pad_token_id] = -100
    model_inputs["labels"] = labels
    return model_inputs

def get_proofnet_dataset(tokenizer, preprocess_function=preprocess_function_proofnet_simple):
    dataset_val = load_dataset("hoskinson-center/proofnet", split='validation')
    dataset_test = load_dataset("hoskinson-center/proofnet", split='test')
    val_dataset = dataset_val.map(lambda examples: preprocess_function(examples, tokenizer), batched=True, remove_columns=["nl_statement", "formal_statement"])
    test_dataset = dataset_test.map(lambda examples: preprocess_function(examples, tokenizer), batched=True, remove_columns=["nl_statement", "formal_statement"])
    return val_dataset, test_dataset

print()

# export PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK=1
os.environ['PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK'] = '1'

# Load Hugging Face token from file
with open(Path("~/keys/hf_file_key.txt").expanduser(), "r") as file:
    hf_token = file.read().strip()

# Set the Hugging Face token as an environment variable
os.environ["HF_TOKEN"] = hf_token

# Login using the token
from huggingface_hub import login
login(token=os.getenv("HF_TOKEN"))

# Load model and tokenizer
pretrained_model_name_or_path = "openai-community/gpt2"
if 'gpt2' in pretrained_model_name_or_path:
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path)
    if tokenizer.pad_token_id is None:
        tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
        print(f'{tokenizer.pad_token=}')
    print(f'{tokenizer.eos_token=}\n{tokenizer.eos_token_id=}')
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path)
    # device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else ("mps" if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else "cpu"))
    # device = torch.device(f"cuda:{0}" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    device = torch.device('cpu')
    print(f'{device=}')
    model = model.to(device)
    max_length: int = tokenizer.model_max_length
    print(f'{max_length=}')

# Define training arguments with memory optimization tricks
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="~/tmp/results",  # Output directory for saving model checkpoints
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,  # Training batch size per device
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,  # Evaluation batch size per device
    max_steps=2,  # Total number of training steps
    logging_dir='~/tmp/logs',  # Directory for storing logs
    logging_steps=10,  # Frequency of logging steps
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,  # Accumulate gradients to simulate a larger batch size
    save_steps=500,  # Save checkpoint every 500 steps
    save_total_limit=3,  # Only keep the last 3 checkpoints
    evaluation_strategy="steps",  # Evaluate model at specified steps
    eval_steps=100,  # Evaluate every 100 steps
    gradient_checkpointing=True,  # Enable gradient checkpointing to save memory
    optim="paged_adamw_32bit",  # Optimizer choice with memory optimization
    learning_rate=1e-5,  # Learning rate for training
    warmup_ratio=0.01,  # Warmup ratio for learning rate schedule
    weight_decay=0.01,  # Weight decay for regularization
    lr_scheduler_type='cosine',  # Learning rate scheduler type
    report_to="none",  # Disable reporting to external tracking tools
    # bf16=torch.cuda.is_bf16_supported(),  # Use BF16 if supported by the hardware
    half_precision_backend="auto",  # Automatically select the best backend for mixed precision
    # dataloader_num_workers=4,  # TODO Number of subprocesses for data loading
    # dataloader_pin_memory=True,  # TODO periphery, Pin memory in data loaders for faster transfer to GPU
    # skip_memory_metrics=True,  # Skip memory metrics to save memory
    # dataloader_prefetch_factor=2,  # TODO periphery, Number of batches to prefetch
    # torchdynamo="nvfuser",  # TODO periphery, Use NVFuser backend for optimized torch operations
    full_determinism=True,  # TODO periphery, Ensure reproducibility
    use_cpu=True,
)

train_dataset, test_dataset = get_proofnet_dataset(tokenizer)

# Initialize the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    # eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
)

# Start training
print(f'\n-- Start training')
trainer.train()

# Save the model and tokenizer
trainer.save_model(output_dir="~/tmp/results")
tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir="~/tmp/results")

but no matter what I do e.g.,

I've forced every possible way I can to have cpu enabled to force it to train at all
use a HF dataset from the internet I've used before
updated pytorch pip install --upgrade torch
Disabled MPS
tried making sure cpu was used
training_args = TrainingArguments(
...
no_cuda=True,
use_mps_device=True if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else False,
...
)
" 1. Verify data types: Ensure that your model and data are using compatible data types. MPS might have issues with certain data types." but it's obvious it should work cuz the HF trainer does this on it's own by fetching the device from my model. I've checked this code before.
yes I did device = torch.device("cpu")

but it doesn't work and I get a very cryptic error I've never seen before and nothing on google shows up:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cget_managed_ptr'
  File "/Users/me/py_proj/py_src/train/hf_trainer_train.py", line 93, in <module>
    trainer.train()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cget_managed_ptr'

what is going on? How do I debug this?

Related to this issue I also have this odd warning, wonder if it's related:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cadam32bit_grad_fp32'


My conda env (locally, in server I'm using venv):
% pip list
Package                 Version     Editable project location
----------------------- ----------- ------------------------------
absl-py                 2.1.0
accelerate              0.32.1
my_proj                 0.0.1       /Users/me/my_proj/py_src
aiohttp                 3.9.5
aiosignal               1.3.1
alembic                 1.13.2
annotated-types         0.7.0
anthropic               0.31.1
anthropic-bedrock       0.8.0
anyio                   4.4.0
attrs                   23.2.0
backoff                 2.2.1
backports.tarfile       1.2.0
bitsandbytes            0.42.0
boto3                   1.34.145
botocore                1.34.145
certifi                 2024.7.4
charset-normalizer      3.3.2
click                   8.1.7
colorlog                6.8.2
contourpy               1.2.1
cycler                  0.12.1
datasets                2.20.0
dill                    0.3.8
distro                  1.9.0
docker-pycreds          0.4.0
docutils                0.21.2
dspy-ai                 2.4.12
evaluate                0.4.2
filelock                3.15.4
fire                    0.6.0
fonttools               4.53.1
frozenlist              1.4.1
fsspec                  2024.5.0
gitdb                   4.0.11
GitPython               3.1.43
greenlet                3.0.3
grpcio                  1.64.1
h11                     0.14.0
httpcore                1.0.5
httpx                   0.27.0
huggingface-hub         0.23.4
idna                    3.7
importlib_metadata      8.0.0
jaraco.classes          3.4.0
jaraco.context          5.3.0
jaraco.functools        4.0.1
Jinja2                  3.1.4
jiter                   0.5.0
jmespath                1.0.1
joblib                  1.3.2
jsonlines               4.0.0
keyring                 25.2.1
kiwisolver              1.4.5
lark-parser             0.12.0
Mako                    1.3.5
Markdown                3.6
markdown-it-py          3.0.0
MarkupSafe              2.1.5
matplotlib              3.9.1
mdurl                   0.1.2
more-itertools          10.3.0
mpmath                  1.3.0
multidict               6.0.5
multiprocess            0.70.16
networkx                3.3
nh3                     0.2.18
nltk                    3.8.1
numpy                   1.26.4
nvidia-htop             1.2.0
openai                  1.35.13
optuna                  3.6.1
packaging               24.1
pandas                  2.2.2
pillow                  10.4.0
pip                     24.0
pkginfo                 1.10.0
platformdirs            4.2.2
plotly                  5.22.0
protobuf                4.25.3
psutil                  6.0.0
pyarrow                 16.1.0
pyarrow-hotfix          0.6
pydantic                2.8.2
pydantic_core           2.20.1
Pygments                2.18.0
pyparsing               3.1.2
python-dateutil         2.9.0.post0
pytz                    2024.1
PyYAML                  6.0.1
readme_renderer         44.0
regex                   2024.5.15
requests                2.32.3
requests-toolbelt       1.0.0
rfc3986                 2.0.0
rich                    13.7.1
s3transfer              0.10.2
safetensors             0.4.3
scikit-learn            1.5.1
scipy                   1.14.0
seaborn                 0.13.2
sentry-sdk              2.10.0
setproctitle            1.3.3
setuptools              69.5.1
six                     1.16.0
smmap                   5.0.1
sniffio                 1.3.1
SQLAlchemy              2.0.31
structlog               24.2.0
sympy                   1.13.0
tenacity                8.5.0
tensorboard             2.17.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.7.2
termcolor               2.4.0
threadpoolctl           3.5.0
tokenizers              0.19.1
torch                   2.2.2
tqdm                    4.66.4
transformers            4.42.4
twine                   5.1.1
typing_extensions       4.12.2
tzdata                  2024.1
ujson                   5.10.0
urllib3                 2.2.2
wandb                   0.17.4
Werkzeug                3.0.3
wheel                   0.43.0
xxhash                  3.4.1
yarl                    1.9.4
zipp                    3.19.2


refs:

https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/what-does-the-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-cget-managed-ptr-mean/100674
https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1269175711420125215
What does the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cget_managed_ptr'" mean?


Do you use a virtual env?

@QianZhang yes I do! always. I can do a pip list in a sec and update the question. I also tried this on GPU (and the gpu machine and force it to use cpu) and it failed with a different error I think. I can update the question in a bit.
